# Search Results Panel for SublimeText 2

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext2

I use Notepad++ on my PC and Sublime Text 2 on my Mac. You can "find all instances" of text in Notepad++, which will then display the find results in a window. In this window I see the line number where the text was found and a snippet of the surrounding text. I find this tremendously useful.

Is there a similar feature in Sublime Text 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Find All and then Cmd+F2 to set bookmarks.

Comment: This is good, thanks. When I do this, I can go to the Goto -> Bookmarks and see the line numbers for each instance of the found text. What about the Find -> Find Results -> Show Results Panel? This option is always disabled for me. It sounds like it could be what I am looking for, but I can't seem to enable this menu option. Thanks.

Comment: The Find Result Panel is for Find In Files. Cmd+Shift+F uncheck "Use Buffer" option and you would see the Find Result Panel. Wasn't sure if you were looking for find in current buffer or find in files.

Comment: You are the man. Do you work for Sublime or something? This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @anazimok, is it possible to show the matched lines only when searching in current file rather than multiple opened files? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Use Find in Files (**Ctrl+Shift+F**), and then select the "**add current file**" option at the end of the "where:" textfield.

Answer (score 5):

if you only want see this in a panel like notepad++,when you search with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, you can click the button "Use Buffer" left to the "find:" then the answer will show in panel down the screen

Answer (score 0):

If the search box you are talking about is indeed the standard search box you can view when you press Ctrl+F or Search->Find, then one way to regain your window is like you do with every other window in Windows that has default handling:

Press Ctrl+F or Search->Find to assure your find window is in foreground and focussed.

```
1)OPress Alt+Space to open the Window Context Menu of your Find window.
2) Press Enter to select the "Move" entry of your context menu.
3) Press one of the Arrow Keys at least once.
4) Move your mouse. The Window should now follow your mouse coursor.  
   Place it wherever you need it, and click.
```

Regards
Mr. Arvind Yadav
www.Objectzoom.com