# notepad++ Find in Files: "Find Results" panel - show lines before/after line matching the search criteria

Tags: notepad++

I recently checked with nodepad++'s 'Find in Files' display of matching lines in the 'Find Result' pane/window.

Like described in [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929527/search-results-panel-for-sublimetext-2), I think I can remember that in the past also lines before and after a 'matching line instance' per file were shown in the 'Find Result' window (maybe this was a setting somewhere).

I cannot find how to enable this in notepad++ in these days, also I could not find information about whether this is offered in the first place.

Was this feature really removed? How would you get it back, or produce a similar (optional) behavior with notepad++?

I know about the 'LineFilter2' plugin and regex application to mark/display lines in *single* file notepad++ tabs.

But this does not work/provide the display I am looking for with the '*Find Result'* pane/window when searching multiple files.

Comment: Could something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239955/7644018) be an alternative?  Another possibility from [notepad++ forum](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/16701/how-to-mark-lines-above-marked-lines/5).

Comment: @Paul T: I found this before as mentioned, _but this does not work/provide the display I am looking for with the 'Find Result' pane/window when searching multiple files._ - unfortunately...